# KOMA-Script scrbook: width of chapter and section number

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, numbering, koma-script

I'm using KOMA-Script’s `scrbook` class and have problems with the Table of Contents.

When the chapter number is too large, the chapter number is glued to the chapter heading. The chapter-section number field is also glued to the section heading. The page numbers of the sections are pushed slightly to the right so that the page numbers for sections do not line up with the page numbers for the chapters.

I have similar issues if the section numbers are too large.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`tocstyle`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle) package and its `KOMAlike` style:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocstyle}

\usetocstyle{KOMAlike} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{100}% just for the example
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\setcounter{section}{10}% just for the example
\section{Title of a Section}
\section{Title of a Section}
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\setcounter{section}{20}% just for the example
\section{Title of a Section}
\section{Title of a Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the answer by Gonzalo and it worked perfectly. Just for the record, I'll add the following comment. I actually use hyperref. When I used Gonzalo's answer yesterday, it *apparently* did not work. Buthttps://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4AIDw7DRmyjeWZCNkZnTFRvdWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: cont ... See (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4AIDw7DRmyjeWZCNkZnTFRvdWs/edit?usp=sharing). The sequence of images explains why you have to had 4 passes. This might be due to hyperref. Thanks to Gonzalo. I did not try Werner's answer but it looks helpful too.

Comment: @user32463 I'm glad we could help. Don't forget that besides up-voting answers you can also accept the one that you consider best solved your problem, by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: These days, you get the following ugly warning when using tocstyle: "Package tocstyle Warning: THIS IS A DEPRECATED ALPHA VERSION! USAGE OF THIS VERSION IS ON YOUR OWN RISK! EVERYTHING MAY HAPPEN! THE PACKAGE IS FROZEN WITH ALL IT'S BUGS! IT WILL BE REMOVED FROM KOMA-SCRIPT SOON! THERE IS NO SUPPORT, IF YOU USE THIS PACKAGE! Maybe it would be better, not to load this package." Just to inform any visitors to this answer.

Comment: About `tocstyle`: "The package has been withdrawn from the koma-script bundle in Juli 2020 and is now considered obsolete."

Answer (score 3):

<sub>A solution not really true to KOMA-script.</sub>

For `\chapter` entries in the ToC, the width of the number is contained within `\@tempdima`. You can update this length using the hook `\raggedchapterentry` (say, empty by default) in the following way:

```
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapterentry}{\setlength{\@tempdima}{3em}}
```

The default length for `\@tempdima` in `\l@chapter` is `1.5em`. So I've doubled it, just for comparison.

`\l@section` governs the placement of the `\section` unit number/title, which is defined as

```
\newcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

within the KOMA-script base class(es). The first length is the width of the unit indentation and the second is the length of the unit number. You could modify this to (say)

```
\renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{3em}{3.5em}}
```

which will align it (horizontally) with the `3em` chapter number (defined above) and use a number width of `3.5em` for `\section`. Here's a complete example:

Original output:

[image]

Updated output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapterentry}{\setlength{\@tempdima}{3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{3em}{3.5em}}
\show\l@chapter
\show\l@section
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{100}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer bases on an old KOMA-Script version. (The `usage` of `\bprot@dottedtocline' is deprecated. Use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` or `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the settings for the entries in TOC, LOF, LOT etc. Addtionally `\raggedchapterentry` should not be missused.)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Starting with **KOMA-Script version 3.27** there is also option `pagenumberwidth` for `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` to adjust the space for the page number. With prefix `toc` it can be used for `\RecdeclareSectionCommand` too.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}[2019/10/12]
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth]{chapter,section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocpagenumberwidth=6ex]% adjust the space for the page number
  {part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{100}% just for the example
\setcounter{page}{998}% just for the example
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\setcounter{section}{10}% just for the example
\section{Title of a Section}
\section{Title of a Section}
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\setcounter{section}{20}% just for the example
\section{Title of a Section}
\section{Title of a Section}
\end{document}
```

---

Starting with **KOMA-Script version 3.20** you can use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2016/10/05]
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth]{chapter,section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocpagenumberbox=\pagenumberbox]
  {part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\newcommand\pagenumberbox[1]{%
  \makebox{\enskip #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{100}% just for the example
\setcounter{page}{998}% just for the example
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\setcounter{section}{10}% just for the example
\section{Title of a Section}
\section{Title of a Section}
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\setcounter{section}{20}% just for the example
\section{Title of a Section}
\section{Title of a Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=3em]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=3em,tocnumwidth=3.5em]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocpagenumberbox=\pagenumberbox]
  {part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\newcommand\pagenumberbox[1]{%
  \makebox[4ex][r]{#1}%
}
```

[image]