# List of Algorithms: space between number and algorithm caption too small

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, algorithm2e

I'm facing a problem with KOMA-Script and `algorithm2e`: algorithm captions in the list of algorithms collide with the numbers preceding them. See the image for an impression. How would I go about fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: [KOMA-Script scrbook: width of chapter and section number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119849/5764) or [Extra space for numbered titles in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13690/5764)

Answer (score 2):

To typeset the entries in the list of algorithms, `algorithm2e` uses

```
\renewcommand*\l@algocf{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{2.3em}}
```

To add some extra spacing between the number and the title, you can redefine `\l@algocg` and use a greater value for the third argument:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}% for the example

\counterwithin{algocf}{section}% for the example I assumed you subordinate algorithm counter to that of the sections
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@algocf{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{3.2em}}% Original {1}{1em}{2.3em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms
\setcounter{chapter}{5}% just for the example
\chapter{Test chapter}
\setcounter{section}{1}% just for the example
\section{Test section}
\setcounter{algocf}{13}% just for the example
\begin{algorithm}[H]
A
\caption{Test algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]