# Spacing between list of listings and algorithms and their reference numbers with tocbasic

Tags: spacing, listings, algorithm2e, tocbasic

Because of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530979/106804) to [Extending table of contents dots up to large page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/530946/106804) I am using `tocbasic` and  would like to add more spacing between the reference numbers in the

- List of listings
- List of algorithms

and the captions. I have been using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383206/106804)

```latex
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3.5em]{tocline}{figure}% for figure entries
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3.5em]{tocline}{table}% for table entries
```

to [Spacing problem at List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187180/106804).

***How can I add some spacing between the numbers and the entries?***

[image]

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[algosection]{algorithm2e} % For writing nice algorithms. 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}  %% The ordering matters here. 
\usepackage{listings} %% The ordering matters here. 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocbasic} % For better TOC alignment
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash,figurewithin=section,tablewithin=section]{caption} % Caption figures and tables nicely. %% After cleveref.

% List of Algorithms (NB, requires french spelling of 'algorithmes')
\renewcommand*{\listalgorithmcfname}{List of algorithms}
\newcommand{\listofalgorithmes}{\tocfile{\listalgorithmcfname}{loa}}

% We want the list of listings to look like all the others. 
\let\Chapter\chapter
\def\chapter{\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}\Chapter}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\chaptermark{#1}}{%
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{\typeout{Chapters patched for list-of-listings.}}{\typeout{Could not patch chapters for list-of-listings.}}
\makeatother

% So Roman page numbers are right aligned. 
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  rightindent=10em,
  pagenumberbox=\pagenumberbox
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table}
\newcommand*\pagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{\hspace{1em}#1}}


\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3.5em]{tocline}{figure}% for figure entries
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3.5em]{tocline}{table}
%\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3.5em]{tocline}{listing}% <- Doesn't work
%\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3.5em]{tocline}{algorithm}% <- Doesn't work

\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}} % Ensures these are numbered enough

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\listofalgorithmes
\listoftodos   
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Arabic numbering starts}
\subsection{Some possibly very long title section that might just decide to span several lines in the table of contents. Why would someone write this, Who knows?}
\lipsum
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{123456789}
\section{Several pages later}
\subsection{Something}
\lipsum
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section{Now we have Roman numbering}
\subsection{Something}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{123}
\section{Several pages later}
\subsection{Something}
\lipsum
\chapter{title}
\section{Some figures}
\subsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{something}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{something}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{something}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{something}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{something}\end{figure}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}\section{Section}\section{Section}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}\section{Section}\section{Section}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

## Solution for algorithms

Taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130370/106804) to [List of Algorithms: space between number and algorithm caption too small](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130355/106804).

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@algocf{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{3.2em}}% Original {1}{1em}{2.3em}
\makeatother
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```latex
\usepackage{tocbasic}[2019/12/23]

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3.5em]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  level:=figure,
  indent:=figure,
  numwidth:=figure,
]{tocline}{table,lstlisting,algocf,todo}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  rightindent=10em,
  pagenumberbox=\pagenumberbox
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table,lstlisting,algocf,todo}
\newcommand*\pagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{\hspace{1em}#1}}
```

Or you could use `dynnumwidth`:

```latex
\usepackage{tocbasic}[2019/12/23]

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  level:=figure,
  indent:=figure,
  numwidth:=figure,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{table,lstlisting,algocf,todo}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  rightindent=10em,
  pagenumberbox=\pagenumberbox
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table,lstlisting,algocf,todo}
\newcommand*\pagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{\hspace{1em}#1}}
```

`dynnumwidth` enlarges the space for the entry number automatically, if the entry number is too long. But it needs an additional run. Then you can use `numsep` to adjust the minimum space between the entry number and the entry text:

```latex
\usepackage{tocbasic}[2019/12/23]

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  numsep=2em,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  level:=figure,
  indent:=figure,
  numwidth:=figure,
  numsep:=figure,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{table,lstlisting,algocf,todo}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  rightindent=10em,
  pagenumberbox=\pagenumberbox
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table,lstlisting,algocf,todo}
\newcommand*\pagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{\hspace{1em}#1}}
```